# Unable to use Toaster in Angular with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, typescript1.5

I have been using angular with typescript but cannot use angular toaster along with typescript any idea??

```
export class notification {


        constructor(private test: ngtoaster.IToasterService) {
            //Error here When I load toaster service if remove that contstructor parma works fine

           //private toaster: ngtoaster.IToasterService
           // this.toaster.toast.timeout = 3000;
           // this.toaster.toast.type = EnergyTechApp.Entity.Constants.info;
           // this.toaster.toast.showCloseButton = true;
        }
}
```

error:Unknown provider: toastrConfigProvider <- toastrConfig <- toastr <- notification 
Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider

I mentioned dependency of 'ngToaster' in all modules and everywhere

Comment: Can you show us "all of the modules and everywhere" you included the service? Because that error message tends to mean that it wasn't included as a dependency in the module or it wasn't referenced in your html file.

Comment: You error is not a typescript error. It's an angular error. I has nothing to do with a d.ts file. I was talking about the `ngToast.js` file that must be referenced in the html file.

Comment: ok , I have referenced it !! I have 'ngToaster' referenced in all modules

Comment: you mean file here https://github.com/tameraydin/ngToast/tree/master/dist  ??? I was referencing this one https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr/tree/master/dist

Comment: Have you tried renaming `test` to `toastr`? Also, according to the documentation, you should be using `toastr` as a the dependency for the module, not `ngToaster`.

Comment: Module 'toastr' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument. - when I gave toastr as dependency instead ngToaster